# Is it true that if $f: S^1 \to S^1$ is the map $z \mapsto z^n$, then the induced map $f_*: H_1(S^1) \to H_1(S^1)$ is given by multiplication by $n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I'm trying to see if this is true, but not sure how to go about it. I know that $f$ induces a map on chains where $C_1(S^1) \to C_1(S^1)$ is given by $\sigma \mapsto f\circ \sigma$.

How would I go about showing that $f_*: H_1(S^1) \to H_1(S^1)$ is given by multiplication by $n$?

Comment: Show that if you have two paths viewed as 1-simplices $\sigma, \phi$ such that the endpoint of $\sigma$ is the start of $\phi$ in $X$ then $\phi * \sigma$ is homologous to $\phi + \sigma$. Then if you denote by $f_\#$ the induced map on chain complexes show that $f_\# (\sigma) = \sigma*...*\sigma$ n-times where $\sigma$ represents the generator in degree $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give a method which uses only the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms and makes no specific reference to *singular* cohomology. This means that the same statement is true for your favourite *generalised* cohomology theory (K-theory, cobordism, $BP$-theory, etc...). It also has the upside that it is topological and quite visual, rather than relying on algebraic manipulations.

To begin, we'll notice that $S^1\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ has a multiplication $\mu:S^1\times S^1\rightarrow S^1$ which turns it into a topological group. The degree $2$ map is then the composite
$$\underline 2:S^1\xrightarrow{\Delta}S^1\times S^1\xrightarrow{\mu}S^1$$
where $\Delta$ is the diagonal map $z\mapsto (z,z)$. Check directly that $\underline 2$ is exactly the map $z\mapsto z^2$. To get the degree $n+1>2$ map we have inductively
$$\underline {(n+1)}:S^1\xrightarrow{\Delta}S^1\times S^1\xrightarrow{\underline n\times 1}S^1\times S^1\xrightarrow{\mu}S^1.$$
For negative $n$ we use the group inverse $z\mapsto z^{-1}$. The identity is the degree $1$ map, and the constant map is the degree $0$ map.

I'll focus from here on the case for $n=2$. The method will make it clear that an inductive step (which I'll leave to you) gives the answer for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

To proceed recall that the wedge, or one-point union, $S^1\vee S^1$ is the quotient space of the disjoint union $S^1\sqcup S^1$ which is obtained by identifying together a single point in each summand. It may be described geometrically as a figure $8$. There is an obvious map
$$c:S^1\rightarrow S^1\vee S^1$$
obtained by pinching together the points $\pm1$. Note that in homology it induces a map
$$c_*:H_1(S^1)\rightarrow H_1(S^1\vee S^1)\cong H_1(S^1)\oplus H_1(S^1).$$

Now, in the category of abelian groups, finite coproducts and finite products coincide (i.e. a finite direct *sum* of abelian groups is isomorphic to the finite direct *product* of the same groups). The point is that the map $c_*$ is determined completely by its composites with the two maps
$$H_1(S^1)\xleftarrow{pr_1}H_1(S^1)\oplus H_1(S^1)\xrightarrow{pr_2}H_1(S^1)$$
which project onto each of the factors.

But with respect to the isomorphism $H_1(S^1\vee S^1)\cong H_1(S^1)\oplus H_1(S^1)$, these projections are just the homomorphisms induced by the maps
$$S^1\xleftarrow{q_1}S^1\vee S^1\xrightarrow{q_2} S^1$$
which crush one side of the figure $8$ to a point and act as the identity on the other. You can check quite easily that there are homotopies
$$q_1\circ c\simeq id_{S^1}\simeq q_2\circ c,$$
and, using the homotopy invariance of homology, conclude that $c_*$ is the homomorphism
$$c_*:x\mapsto x\oplus x.$$

Now, using the same homotopies you just wrote down, you can check that the composite
$$S^1\xrightarrow{c}S^1\vee S^1\hookrightarrow S^1\times S^1$$
is homotopic to the diagonal map
$$S^1\rightarrow S^1\times S^1,\qquad z\mapsto (z,z).$$
It is also clear that the composite
$$S^1\vee S^1\hookrightarrow S^1\times S^1\xrightarrow{\mu}S^1$$
is the fold map $\nabla:S^1\vee S^1\rightarrow S^1$, which is the identity on each factor.

The point is that the degree $2$ map I wrote down at the beginning is homotopic to the composite
$$S^1\xrightarrow{c}S^1\vee S^1\xrightarrow{\nabla}S^1.$$
Thus to compute $\underline 2_*:H_1S^1\rightarrow H_1S^1$ it suffices to compute
the action of the composite
$$H_1(S^1)\xrightarrow{c_*}H_1(S^1)\oplus H_1(S^1)\xrightarrow{\nabla_*}H_1(S^1).$$
We computed $c_*$ above. To get $\nabla_*$ we observe that not only does the wedge axiom tell you that there is an isomorphism
$$H_1(S^1)\oplus H_1(S^1)\xrightarrow{\cong}H_1(S^1\oplus S^1)$$
but it also tells you *how* this isomorphism is induced. Namely, it says that this isomorphism is induced by the sum of the maps induced by the inclusions
$$S^1\xrightarrow{in_1} S^1\vee S^1\xleftarrow{in_2}S^1.$$
Using this observation, we check directly that $\nabla_*$ is the map
$$\nabla_*:H_1(S^1)\oplus H_1(S^1)\rightarrow H_1(S^1),\qquad (x,y)\mapsto x+y.$$

Putting everything together, we have that $\underline{2}_*: H_1(S^1)\rightarrow H_1(S^1)$ is the map $(\nabla\circ c)_*=\nabla_*\circ c_*$, which is exactly the map
$$x\mapsto x\oplus x\mapsto x+x=2x.$$
i.e., it is multiplication by $2$. Cue induction.

Comment: At the point where we conclude $c_*\colon x\mapsto x\oplus x$, how do we deduce that $S^1\to S^1\vee S^1 \to S^1$ indeed induces $x\mapsto x$ in homology? From the homotopy equivalence $q_i\circ c\simeq\mathrm{id}$, all we know is that this map should be bijective. In other words, why is $c_*\colon x\mapsto x\oplus x$, and not for example $x\mapsto -x\oplus -x$?

Comment: @Gargantuar actually functorality (which is certainly included in the ES axioms) gives $q_{i*}\circ c_*=(q_i\circ c)_*=(id_{S^1})_*=id_{H_*S^1})$, rather than the negative of this equation. If you're asking about the isomomorphism $H_*S^1\oplus H_*S^1\xrightarrow{\cong}H_*(S^1\vee S^1)$, the ES axioms actually require that it be induced by adding together the maps induced by the two inclusions $S^1\hookrightarrow S^1\vee S^1$.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the [argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle) to show that the map $f(z) = z^n$ encircles the origin $n$ times as $z = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$ orbits the origin once (i.e. as $\theta$ runs through $[0,2\pi]$).  (If needed, you might also show that $|f(z)| = 1$.)

Now we know the generator of the abelian group $\langle c \rangle = H_1(S^1)$ is sent to $f_*(c) = n c$.  As a consequence, we know that, for all $k \in \Bbb{Z}$, $f_*(kc)= nkc$.  That is, $f_*$ is the multiply by $n$ map.  (You can also show this directly from the argument principle: $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}k\theta}$ encloses the origin $k$ times while $f(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}k\theta})$ encloses the origin $nk$-times).

Comment: this doesn't seem like a full answer to me. What definition of homology are you using? How do you know that wrapping around $n$-times is multiplication by $n$ on homology?  I would say that this is clear if we are using cellular homology, or if you finish by arguing that the Hurewicz map is an isomorphism, or maybe even using singular homology. I just think some words need to be said as to what $f_*(c)=nc$.