# Show that the map $\phi_k : z \mapsto z^k$ from $S^1$ to $S^1$ induces multiplication by $k$ on $H_1.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Show that the map $\phi_k : z \mapsto z^k$ from $S^1$ to $S^1$ induces multiplication by $k$ on $H_1.$

This question is appeared in the midterm exam at our institute which I am unable figure out properly as how to proceed. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with $CW$ complex ?

Comment: @jacopoburelli yes sir I am familiar with CW complexes.

Comment: If you know that $\phi_k$ induces multiplication by $k$ on $\pi_1$, you can apply naturality of the Hurewicz homomorphism.

Comment: @Frederik I am not aware of Hurewicz homomorphism.

Comment: There is a solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583641/is-it-true-that-if-f-s1-to-s1-is-the-map-z-mapsto-zn-then-the-induced/3584276).

Comment: Do you know the Hurewicz homomorphism $\pi_1(X) \to H_1(X)$?

Comment: @Paul Frost I am not aware of that.

Comment: @Paul Frost can you please explain?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1949774. The map $h: \pi_1(X,x_0) \to H_1(X)$  is called the Hurewicz homomorphism in dimension $1$. If the fundamental group is abelian (as for $X= S^1$), it is an isomorphism. Since it is well-known that $(\phi_k)_*$  is multiplication by $k$ on $\pi_1$, the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer to this question can be quite short - or quite long depending on your familiarity with algebraic topology. The short answer is: View the generator of $H_1(S^1)$, call it $\gamma$ as the loop which goes around $S^1$ precisely once. Then, the morphism $z \mapsto z^k$ will make $\gamma$ wrap around your $S^1$ precisely $k$-times, and therefore maps $\gamma$ of $H_1(S^1)$ to $k \gamma$. Since it induces multiplication by $k$ on the generator of $H_{1}(S^1)$ it must induce multiplication by $k$ on the whole of $H_1$.

This also agrees with the idea that the degree of a map is equal to the number of pre-images of a generic point - look at the map $z \mapsto z^{k}$, and choose a random point, say $p$, on $S^{1}$ in the image. Then, there are $k$ points in the pre-image which get mapped to $p$ which are $\frac{2\pi}{k}$ radians apart.

Comment: How do you know that if a morphism wraps around the circle $j$-times then it will induce multiplication by $k$ on the generator of $H_1(S^1).$ Aren't you using any specific relation between $\pi_1(S^1)$ and $H_1(S^1)$ here?